# How to bind a key to press two separate keys

Tags: macos, keyboard, games, keybindings

In other words, if I press "x", it registers as me pressing "a" and "b" sequentially.

I run Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. A Karabiner solution eludes me, thus I am researching more.

Comment: There is no question in the question? Also, which platform/OS version are you using?

Comment: Apple.stackexchange, so I was hoping people would assume Mac. Sorry for not specifying earlier, but this is Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. The Karabiner solution below is the closest thing to a solution, but not quite, thus I am researching more.

Answer (score 2):

To make this work you have to use a third party tool: Karabiner.

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
5. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
6. Enter the customized keycode

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <root>
       <item>
           <name>X to A and B</name>
           <appendix>When you type X, A and B are written</appendix>
           <identifier>x2ab</identifier>
           <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::X, KeyCode::A, KeyCode::B</autogen>
       </item>
   </root>
   ```
7. Save the file
8. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
9. Hit the ReloadXML button
10. Enable the remapping. It should be listed at the beginning.

You can restrict the keybinding to particular apps if needed by adding additional tags. Leave a comment if you want to know how or specify your question.

Comment: How should I make it so that if G is pressed, both the up arrow key and "w" are pressed at the same time? Also for a specific app. Thanks for the answer though! And whilst I'm waiting, I'll also try to figure it out.

Comment: Note that this answer is outdated. private.xml has been replaces with a .json file: https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/issues/850

Comment: This one using search is very useful for finding complex rules to start with https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/