# Using Karabiner for multi key to multi key remapping

Tags: karabiner

I have been using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) for some key remappings on a macbook pro. I have successfully (and very satisfyingly) remapped right-cmd + up arrow and right-cmd + down arrow to page up and page down.

I would like to do further remappings, such as remap shift + enter so that it will give me line breaks in messages, or cmd + anglebrackets to switch workspaces. Unfortunately the only way I know to do these things are with two key strokes in the first place (option + enter for messages new lines and control + arrow keys to switch workspaces). How can I use karabiner to make two key presses map to two other key presses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I solved my two specific problems, though I am still not sure how I would replicate multiple key presses if more than one of them were not modifier keys.

Put the following two json files in user/.config/karabiner/assets/complex_modifications

```
{
  "title": "Shift + Enter",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Shift + Enter to Option Enter (newline in messenger)",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "return_or_enter",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "shift"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock",
                "option"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "return_or_enter",
              "modifiers": [
                "option"
            ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This one (shift enter) is really frustrating me but not because of karabiner. In messenger i need to option+enter to get a new line character, but in the browser option-enter refuses to do anything. I wish I could get a key combination that does a consistent "safe" new line character, rather than making me fear I am going to accidentally press enter to send or complete or publish or something like that.

```
{
  "title": "cmd + angle brackets for workspaces",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Use CMD + comma  (left angle bracket key) to switch to  left workspace",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "comma",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "command"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock",
                "option",
                "control"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "left_arrow",
              "modifiers": [
                "control"
            ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Use CMD + .  (right angle bracket key) to switch to  left workspace",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "period",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "command"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock",
                "option",
                "control"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "right_arrow",
              "modifiers": [
                "control"
            ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

A solution to a similar question can be found here: [How to bind a key to press two separate keys](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224861/how-to-bind-a-key-to-press-two-separate-keys)

Answer (score 1):

You can send multiple key codes like so in the `to` array. In this example, I'm using the Insert key (on my Microsoft keyboard) to send the characters in `hello` one at a time.

```
{
    "description": "(Terminal) Insert",
    "manipulators": [
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "bundle_identifiers": [
                        "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$"
                    ],
                    "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                }
            ],
            "from": {
                "key_code": "insert"
            },
            "to": [
                {
                    "key_code": "h"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "e"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "l"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "l"
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "o"
                }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome!  Thanks for taking the time to answer. It’s helpful to put a short explanation so that readers of different technical proficiencies can grasp what you’re trying to convey.

Comment: It looks like the later ones override the previous ones

Comment: @theonlygusti I'm no expert here, but the example I showed in the answer certainly works for me, and emits each character in order.

Comment: @stubert I believe you, [it looks like something funky happens for the function key though](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/458687/150109)