# How do I make bind keys to produce a new line character without a return_or_enter press

Tags: karabiner

How do I use Karabiner to take certain key presses (shift+enter, for example) and give me a new line character. Note that I do NOT want to just replicate return_or_enter, as enter is a very overloaded key that can sometimes execute drastic behavior. I want to behave like it is pasting in a new line character.

Somewhat similar to this question here ([Using Karabiner for multi key to multi key remapping](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377256/using-karabiner-for-multi-key-to-multi-key-remapping)) except I am trying to figure out how to replicate a single character rather than multiple characters, to solve the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried posting this as an issue in Github, as well as asking your question on the Karabiner Google Group? I encourage you to do those steps as you're more likely to find people there who have the specific knowledge to help. Here are the URLs: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/contact.html

Comment: You can use macOS's own text replacer to make a new line, by simply pasting one in & giving it a command. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jms5t.png You can't see it, of course, but it's a new line.