# Karabiner remap unless other keys are pressed

Tags: macos, keyboard, monterey, karabiner

I found that I can remap several keys pressed at the same time: [Karabiner-Elements complex manipulation: from.simultaneous](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/complex-modifications-manipulator-definition/from/simultaneous/)

```json
{
    "type": "basic",
    "from": {
        "simultaneous": [
            {
                "key_code": "a"
            },
            {
                "key_code": "s"
            },
            {
                "key_code": "d"
            }
        ],
        "modifiers": {
            "optional": ["any"]
        }
    },
    "to": [
        {
            "key_code": "mission_control"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I want to *always*  remap the <kbd>fn</kbd> to the right <kbd>Shift</kbd>, *except* when the <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, etc. are also pressed.

That's because I want <kbd>fn</kbd> to be the right <kbd>Shift</kbd>, but still be able to use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, etc. as  shortcuts to control brightness and volume. My original mapping

```
{
  "type": "basic",
  "from": {
    "apple_vendor_top_case_key_code": "keyboard_fn"
  },
  "to": [
    {
      "key_code": "right_shift"
    }
  ]
}
```

stops my system-wide brightness controls from working (I use <kbd>fn</kbd> + the function key to trigger the macOS binding instead of the app's binding).

My other workaround attempt was to map to both the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the function key at the same time:

```json
"to": [
  {
    "apple_vendor_top_case_key_code": "keyboard_fn"
  },
  {
    "key_code": "right_shift"
  }
]
```

Unfortunately, only the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> gets detected. If I swap their positions in the list, then only the function key gets detected.

Comment: Hey I have almost the same need, did you eventually figure it out?

Answer (score -1):

I just saw via [Michael Tsai](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2023/05/02/fn-key-reserved-for-system-applications/) and [Marcin Krzyzanowski](https://twitter.com/krzyzanowskim/status/1644070064738521090) that the <kbd>fn</kbd> is reserved for system use. This doesn't feel like a very satisfactory answer, but maybe that explains why things don't work well with it.

Comment: I think is not true for Karabinier which can remap fn. The links refure to Apple's own Keybindings